# Jquery datepicker not working when add in documnet ready

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker, replacewith

I have a custom datepicker like this

```
<input id='mydatepicker' data-mddatetimepicker='true' data-placement='left' data-trigger='focus' data-enabletimepicker='false' />
```

When I use it in html code work well. For example :

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="mydiv">
    <input id='mydatepicker' data-mddatetimepicker='true' data-placement='left' data-trigger='focus' data-enabletimepicker='false' />
</div>
```

But I want add this datepicker using `replaceWith` in `document.ready`.

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="mydiv">
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#div2").replaceWith("<input id='mydatepicker' data-mddatetimepicker='true' data-placement='left' data-trigger='focus' data-enabletimepicker='false' />");
    });
</script>
```

But when page loaded just display an simple input without datepicker. How can I do this replacement correctly?

I use this [library for datepicker](https://github.com/Mds92/MD.BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker)

Comment: Are you using a date picker library? because i run your code and all i can see is an input with not date picker

Comment: @TamirAbutbul Yes i use a library for datepicker. I think `scripts` and `css` file dose not load when use `replaceWith`

Comment: Could you add a snippet with the library included? If we could have a runnable example with the working code it will be easier to answer your question

Comment: Your datepicker (library) is initialising in its own `doc.ready` (or similar) - when the datepicker initialises, it uses the `data-` attributes to build the datepicker UI.   As you add these *after* the library init, it doesn't pick them up.   Try adding your own doc.ready before the `<script src='datepicker.js`>` that loads the library.   Alternatively, you'll need to call the library's `init` function, whatever that may be.  If you provide details as to which library it is (of the 10,000+ datepickers) we might be able to help you more.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks, The question was edited and the library link was placed at the end of the question

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks a lot. I put the library scripts after `replaceWith` and it worked correctly.

Comment: Alternatively, you *can* initialise the datepickers after making DOM changes (eg if it's later in the page life-cycle), your library page shows you how to use js to init a datepicker rather than using `data-` attributes: https://github.com/Mds92/MD.BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker#how-to-use

Answer (score 1):

Once you replace `#div2` with your input html, you need to initialize your datepicker with follwoing code as suggested in documentation [[1]](https://github.com/Mds92/MD.BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker#how-to-use).

```
const dtp1Instance = new mds.MdsPersianDateTimePicker(document.getElementById('dtp1'), {
  targetTextSelector: '[data-name="dtp1-text"]',
  targetDateSelector: '[data-name="dtp1-date"]',
});
```

See the following example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#div2").replaceWith("<input id='mydatepicker' data-mddatetimepicker='true' data-placement='left' data-trigger='focus' data-enabletimepicker='false' data-name='dtp1-text' />");
  
  const dtp1Instance = new mds.MdsPersianDateTimePicker(document.getElementById('mydatepicker'), {
  targetTextSelector: '[data-name="dtp1-text"]',
  targetDateSelector: '[data-name="dtp1-date"]',
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://mds92.github.io/MD.BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker/src/mds.bs.datetimepicker.style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mds92.github.io/MD.BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker/src/mds.bs.datetimepicker.js"></script>



<div class="col-md-4" id="mydiv">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initialize the datepicker after replacing the content. Something like

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#div2").replaceWith(parameters);  
        $("#mydatepicker").datetimepicker(parameters);
    });
```

Comment: This will very much depend on which datepicker OP is using.   There are 1,000s and each will require a different method to initialise (if possible).

Comment: OPs datepicker can be initialised in this way, shown on the github page: https://github.com/Mds92/MD.BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker#how-to-use